# how to verify that google analytics is working correctly on a subdomain (no access to root domain)

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to add google analytics to a project that is located under a subdomain.  The subdomain has been was pointed to my my project by the domain owner, so I do not have access to the domain itself.

When I add the tracking code the status (shown under Property > Tracking Info)

> Status: Tracking Not Installed
>
> Last checked: 04-Jan-2014 00:00:05 PST
>
> The Google Analytics tracking code has not been detected on your
> website's home page. For Analytics to function, you or your web
> administrator must add the code to each page of your website.

Is there any way to verify the tracking code is installed on the subdomain without having to access the domain root?

Although the tracking status is uninstalled, I am getting activity in **Standard Reports > Realtime**.

Does this mean that it is working despite the status report?

Am I likely to get correct tracking information with this setup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need access to the root domain and if the realtime statistics track traffic then most likely your GA setup works correctly. Most likey you did not implement the code at the place in the source code where Google expects it (which usually works but is still flagged as an error in verification).

If you use Google Chrome as browser you can additionally use two nice extensions to verify that your setup is correct:

[Google Tag Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en) - verifys various Google Tags without mch detail

[Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) - provides some detail which data is sent to google, which plugins (e.g. ecommerce) are loaded by the analytics code etc.